# Python Socketio requires ascii

Tags: python, socket.io, ascii

In python socketio it gives an error related to ascii on this line of handlers.py

("Access-Control-Max-Age", 3600)

I replaces 3600 with '3600' and it works.

Why does it have this behavior? I am using python 2.7 is it related to python 3?

Thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with Python 3, just that it is expecting a string and not an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in `gevent-socketio`:

https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/pull/221